# Multiple await's inside an async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I have a method

```
public async void getResult ()
```

That relies on 2 await responses inside of it.

This is the 1st: await:

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { 
                    try 
                    {
                        scannedItem = getScannedItem(); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception exe) 
                    { }
```

And the 2nd await await call that uses **scannedItem** from above

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { 
                    try
                    {
                        getResultsScannedItem = results(ScannedItem); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception exe) 
                    { }
```

I want to have this all execute from one button. However, the second await never gets executed. Can I even have two awaits inside a method? Bit confused on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put the second task's body in the first task? ie. `await Task.Factory.StartNew( ()=> { try { scannedItem = getScannedItem(); getResultsScannedItem = result( scannedItem ); } ...`

Comment: @clcto I tried putting it inside the first one, but I get the error: "The 'await' operator can only be used when its containing lambda expression is marked with the 'async' modifier"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple awaits inside a single method .. but these don't look like awaitable Tasks .. you are simply wrapping them up with a Task Factory.

You also seem to be swallowing whatever exception is probably happening within the code.

Try changing to:

```
await Task.Run(() => scannedItem = getScannedItem());

await Task.Run(() => getResultsScannedItem = results(ScannedItem));
```

Step through it with the debugger and see if its running or an exception is happening.

Comment: Just taking out the `try` and `catch` is worth a +1 in itself.

Comment: I would also add a note about the void return type. You should never return void on an async methode except for event handlers.

`public async void getResult ()` should become `public async Task getResult ()`

Comment: Yeah .. should return `Task`

Comment: How would I go about setting that up with my code? @tequilaslammer

Comment: As I have written, just replace `void` with `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public async void getResult ()
{
     ScannedItem scannedItem;
     try 
     {
        scannedItem = await getScannedItem(); 
        getResultsScannedItem = await results(scannedItem);   
     } catch (Exception exe) { }
}
```

You should add "async" to getScannedItem and results functions. Hope it helps.